# Import from Excel to datatable for .xls and .xlsx versions

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to Import Excel data to a SQL database. I've this working for excel workbooks with a xls extension (Ver-97). See below the code I'm using for this import:

```
MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source='" & fname & "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")

MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet" & var01 & "$]", MyConnection)
MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "ImportTable")
```

Note: var01 is the worksheet the user can select.

As stated this works fine and no issues. However when I'm trying to import Excel workbooks with higher version I'm getting error messages.
See below code I'm using for this import:

```
MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & fname & "';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0; HDR=YES; IMEX=1;")

MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet" & var01 & "$]", MyConnection)
MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "ImportTable")
```

Note: I'm determining the workbook extension and based on this extension I'm select one of the above 2 code options.

Any advise would be highly appreciated in order to settle this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The part after `Extended Properties=` should be quoted (single or double quotes), while the `Data Source=` part doesn't need to be. You didn't mention the error(s) you're receiving. Maybe an error states that the Provider is not registered? Post the exception details (copy/paste the text).

Comment: If you're importing straight HTML (i.e. DataGrid) into Excel then the newer versions will throw warning messages when you try to open them. You'll have to strip all HTML.

Comment: @JohnPete22 I don't understand your comment. I didn't see HTML mentioned at all. The title says "Import from Excel"